# Magento 1.9.3.2 missing product images

Tags: magento-1.9, api, image

I have noticed in my backend that some products have broken image links. Thus, placeholder gets used on frontend.

I would like to get a list of products that has the placeholder as it's image on the frontend. I have written the following, but it is not working correctly:

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

error_reporting(1);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

foreach($_products as $_product){
    if($_product->getImageUrl()){
        echo($_product->getImageUrl(). $_product->getSku()."</br>");
    }
}?>
```

Update of new code I have tried:

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

error_reporting(1);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

foreach($_products as $_product){
    if (!file_exists(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config') ->getMediaUrl( $_product->getImage()))) {
    echo $_product->getSku(). "<br/>";
}
        //echo(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config') ->getMediaUrl( $_product->getImage())."</br>");

}?>
```

Still not doing what I need

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565377/how-can-i-find-all-products-without-images-in-magento (Aaron Pollack's answer)

Comment: @jscar That is to find products without any images. Some image files look to have not been transferred over, so database points to image files that are not present, meaning placeholder is used. I need to just find products with broken images to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
foreach($_products as $_product){
    $allImages = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
    echo "Product ".$_product->getSku()."<br>";
    foreach($allImages as $_image){
        if (!file_exists($_image->getPath())) {
            echo "Missing Images <br>";
            echo $_image->getPath()."<br>";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

It will give you products with List of Missing Images. If there is no missing image, it will show only product sku.

Comment: Is there a way I could adapt this to get products with any image as placeholder ?

Comment: @VaishalPatel, please check updated answer, it will display any image which is missing.

Comment: shall give this a go now, thank you for the help thus far :)